# Polkadot `payment_queryInfo` returning Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed

Tags: substrate, polkadot, polkadot-js

I was trying to query `payment_queryInfo` on current Westend testnet, and the following payload used to works at spec 9430.

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "payment_queryInfo",
    "params": [
        "0x41028400088ec8045cd8e9fbdd7080021030c5bf7240c9ea36a0648ea3bbe07d54de5d4d0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a50348000402002c50932cfc2b166f444027517b3421ddb59c64162f090197e4ccac19c30c237b0700e40b5402",
        "0x9ee56bc6165d9935abdbc2732cad4f44db4a8b08765c2e7a195c832946e64628"
    ],
    "id": 1
}
```

But right now it will returns

```
WASM backtrace:
error while executing at wasm backtrace:
    0: 0x68d15 - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind
    1: 0xd10b - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::h3e1dd3d08288569e
    2: 0x38dda9 - <unknown>!TransactionPaymentApi_query_info
```

I know this RPC method id deprecated so I tried to switch to `state_call` with the following request:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "state_call",
    "params": [
        "TransactionPaymentApi_query_info",
        "0x41028400088ec8045cd8e9fbdd7080021030c5bf7240c9ea36a0648ea3bbe07d54de5d4d0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a50348000402002c50932cfc2b166f444027517b3421ddb59c64162f090197e4ccac19c30c237b0700e40b5402",
        "0x9ee56bc6165d9935abdbc2732cad4f44db4a8b08765c2e7a195c832946e64628"
    ],
    "id": 1
}
```

but still it is returning:

```
WASM backtrace:
error while executing at wasm backtrace:
    0: 0x68d15 - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind
    1: 1: 0xd10b - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::h3e1dd3d08288569e
    2: 0x38dda9 - <unknown>!TransactionPaymentApi_query_info
```

Anyone has any clue on why this error is popping up?

Do I need to update my metadata or encoding method?

Thanks